# Splitting a Ruby hash into sorted keys / associated values

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a hash in Ruby like this:

```
d = {1 => 'one', 3 => 'three', 2 =>'two'}
```

and I wish to get

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

that is, I want the sorted keys in `x`, and the corresponding values in `y`. I potentially want to use a custom sort order for `x`.

**What's the cleanest, simplest way to do this?**

Comment: Might I ask why you have a hash with numeric keys instead of an array? Or does this make more sense on your real data set?

Comment: absolutely it makes more sense with my real data set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy:

```
x,y = d.sort.transpose
```

Or, with a custom sort:

```
x,y = d.sort_by {|k,v| whatever}.transpose
```

Comment: transpose = unzip ... odd naming choice but has my vote as well

Answer (score 8):

my original answer

```
x = d.keys.sort
y = x.map {|k| d[k]}
```

but you should also see glenn mcdonald's answer

```
x,y = d.sort.transpose
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x, y = d.keys.sort{|a,b| a <=> b}.inject([]){|result, key| result << [key, d[key]]}.transpose
```

... made the sort explicit so you can change it to whatever you like.